# Typeorm: loadEagerRelations option unexpected behaviour?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/f85f436f51fb000cd9959b44e8d7a79bf0cd10ab/src/find-options/FindOptionsUtils.ts#L244-L247

It seems that here `loadEagerRelations` option is not considered. This leads to **very very slow** query (for example in find and findOne) when more relations are given in `relations` array option.

Example:

```js
const father: Father= await this.fatherRepo.findOne({
     where: { id },
     relations: ['son'],
     loadEagerRelations: false
 });
```

This ignore each eager relation for the Father entity (which is right because of `loadEagerRelations: false`), but each eager relation of Son is fully loaded (recursively).

Comment: I'm having this issue with v0.2.45